# Convert a string with someone's name into initials?

Tags: c

I just want to get the user to input a string of their name, and my program iterates through the string and converts it into initials. It then outputs the initials. For example, input = `John Darly Smith`; output = `J.D.S`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[50];
    char initials[5];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, 10, stdin);

    initials[0] = name[0];

    while (name[i] != '\0') {
        if (name[i] == ' ') {
            initials[j] = name[i];
            initials[j + 1] = '.';
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s", initials);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** The code does not work the way I intend it to. When I input something like `John Smith`, it outputs `J .`

Comment: What is your question? Does the code given work, if not what happens?

Comment: in `if(name[i] == ' '){

        initials[j] = name[i];` why do you expect `name[i]` to be anything but a space?

Comment: The number in fgets() should be larger, but not more than 49.

Comment: @Ben ah yeah I see my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Maybe consider [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: `fgets(name, 10, stdin);` will not fully read `"John Smith"`.  Buffer is too small by at least 1.

Comment: @Arif Burhan Disagree about "but not more than 49".  Should use `fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);` (50).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[50] = " ", initials[10] = " ";
    int counter_n = 1;
    int counter_i = 2;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

    initials[0] = name[0];
    initials[1] = '.';

    while (name[counter_n] != '\0') {
        if (name[counter_n] == ' ') {
            initials[counter_i] = name[counter_n + 1];
            counter_n++;
            initials[counter_i + 1] = '.';
            counter_i += 2;     
        }
        counter_n++;            
    }
    initials[counter_i] = '\0';

    printf("Your initials are: %s\n", initials);

    return 0;
}
```

- fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin); reads at most (sizeof(name) - 1) chars, leaves one for '\0'. In this case sizeof(name) = 50, so fgets() will read at most 49 characters.
- Add a '.' after the first initial and let the counters start at name[1] and initial[2].
- Iterate properly through the arrays, you're not incrementing the counters correctly in your code.

Comment: `fgets` reads in at most one less than size characters. So E.g `fgets(name, 50, stdin);` is OK. the case of `49`, max read 48 characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your while loop, you are setting name[i] to a space.

```
while(name[i] != '\0'){
    if(name[i] == ' '){
        // Selecting the next letter instead of a space
        initials[j] = name[i + 1]; // i + 1 instead of i
        initials[j + 1] = '.';
        j += 2; // You are also only jumping over the initial not the dot
    }
    i++;
}
```

You also need to put a dot after the first initial.

Comment: Be careful not to walk past the end of your array in `name[i+1]`. Include a check or something.

Comment: I wouldn't do this, what if someone put a name " John Smith ", you need to suppress spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications in your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char name[50];
char initials[7]; //at least 7 for 3 chars, 3 dots, 1 terminating char.
int i = 0;
int j = 0;   //No need to do special handling for first char

printf("Enter your name: ");
fgets(name, 49, stdin);  // changed to 49

//Removed: No need to do special handling for first char

char c=name[i];  //Need to save initial somewhere.

while(name[i] != '\0'){

    if(name[i] == ' '){

        initials[j] = c;
        initials[j + 1] = '.';
        j+=2;
        c = name[i+1];
    }

    i++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

sample to fix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LEN 50 // 49 + 1

int main(void){
    char name[MAX_LEN];
    char initials[MAX_LEN/2];//5 is small
    char prev = ' ';
    int i, j = 0;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);//To use sizeof(name) to the buffer size

    for(i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if(name[i] != ' ' && prev == ' '){//edge of top of word
            initials[j++] = toupper(name[i]);
            initials[j++] = '.';
        }
        prev = name[i];
    }
    if(j)
        --j;//Back One for last '.'
    initials[j] = '\0';//set null character

    printf("\"%s\"\n", initials);

    return 0;
}
```